# Product not showing in shop woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm posting many products in woocommerce by wp_insert_post.
All posts are not showing in shop and category.

I must open Post and click On update too showing in shop and category.

Any hook to open post and update?

Comment: Share the code you wrote without looking at your code how can anyone give you the idea what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Upon creation of the post, you have to set its meta field `_visibility` to `visible`:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility' , 'visible' );
```

Comment: Your parameters are wrong, please use single ' or double " quotations for strings instead of tilde `.